# Use of "simple-template-id" in type specifiers

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, types

In the C++11 Standard, sections **dcl.type.simple** and **dcl.type.elab** state that type specifiers can include *simple-template-id*. On the other hand, according to section **temp.names**, a *simple-template-id* could denote a function template specialization. Is it really possible to use a function template specialization to specify a type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 7.1.6.2/2 The other simple-type-specifiers specify either a previously-declared user-defined **type** or one of the fundamental types (3.9.1).

Emphasis mine. Function template specialization is not a type.